# id/class based selector v/s forms based selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

Given the following HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="amazon_activated" /> 
    </legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Amazon Data
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

next code allows hide/show the data container table related to the checkbox:

```
$("input[name='amazon_activated']").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("legend").next("table").toggle( $(this).is(":checked") );
});
```

and next code it should init the `hide/show` state after page's load:

```
if ( ! $("input[name='amazon_activated']").is(":checked")){
    $(this).parent("legend").next("table").hide();
}
```

Well, it is failing.

I already know why: `this` refers to the `page` element, not the `checkbox` element.

---

So I wonder:

Is it the best policy **immediately choose** an `id/class`:

```
$("#id")
```

for the important elements in order to facilitate their control through jquery, over form-based selectors?:

```
$("input[name='amazon_activated']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to all for your answers. All have been very helpful (I give +1 to all).**

I want to add my final solutions that takes in account your tips.

Indeed there are several `checkbox` elements involved, so I have **cached** them and use an **associative array** to iterate over it (**avoiding add more id/class**).

```
var checkboxElements = {
    "amazon_activated" : $("input[name='amazon_activated']"),
    "clickbank_activated" : $("input[name='clickbank_activated']"),
    "ebay_activated" : $("input[name='ebay_activated']")
}

$.each(checkboxElements, function(i, el){
    $(el).parent("legend").next("table").toggle( $(el).is(":checked") );
    $(el).click(function(){
        $(el).parent("legend").next("table").toggle( $(el).is(":checked") );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cache the element.

```
var element = this;
```

When `this` is in the right context.

---

You usually code Javascript for a given markup, not the other way around.  ID's and classes have meaning other than being used as selectors.

Comment: No, I've addressed the issue. Don't add unnecessary classes or ID's. Instead, once you find the element you want, save it in a variable and use it instead of the out-of-context this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can cache your elements at the top of the outer function. It will be convenient to use them in other places. Also, caching elements will also enhance the performance. 
You can do something like this:

```
var input = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    table = $("fieldset table");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ! $("input[name='amazon_activated']").is(":checked")){
    $(this).parent("legend").next("table").hide();
}
```

within above code `this` belong to page element scope, where

```
$("input[name='amazon_activated']").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("legend").next("table").toggle( $(this).is(":checked") );
});
```

in above code `this` belongs to `input[name='amazon_activated']`'s callback scope which point to `input[name='amazon_activated']`.

So to make active first code you should try

```
if ( ! $("input[name='amazon_activated']").is(":checked")){
    $("input[name='amazon_activated']").parent("legend").next("table").hide();
}
```

**Its better to keep reference of input in a variable and use that**

```
var checkboxElement = $("input[name='amazon_activated']"); // you can also use id
```

then you this like

```
if ( ! checkboxElement.is(":checked")){
    checkboxElement.parent("legend").next("table").hide();
}

checkboxElement.click(function(){
    $(this).parent("legend").next("table").toggle( $(this).is(":checked") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason every answer is telling you to cache your objects is that it will be tremendously faster. To answer the specific question, disregarding the rest, i.e.:

> Is it the best policy immediately choose an id/class for the important
>   elements in order to facilitate their control through jquery, over
>   form-based selectors?

First, I would say "attribute selectors" over "form-based selectors" as I don't believe jQuery distinguishes between, say `$('input[name="amazon_activated"]')` and `$('a[href="#"]')` as far as how it searches.

That said, the general rule of thumb is:

> id selectors are faster than class selectors are faster than attribute
>   selectors.

So, if all you care about is jQuery speed, that's key. However, adding ids and classes, only for the sake of targeting via jQuery could slow down your page load times more than the corresponding speed-up in selector performance.

In summary to this overly-long answer:

- Cache the result of a jQuery selector when possible
- Use ids and classes when possible, but
- Don't add unnecessary ids and classes unless testing proves them necessary